# Is there a tkinter equivalent for Perl/Tk's Scrolled pseudo-widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

Perl/Tk has a pseudo-widget Tk::Scrolled that takes as its argument another widget and adds a corresponding scrollbar according to options (where to put it in relation to the widget and if to show at all if there is nothing to scroll).  For example, to have a listbox with a scrollbar to the right that disappears if the listbox can display all entries you just have to say:

```
my $Listbox = $MW->Scrolled ('Listbox', -scrollbars => 'oe');
```

Has tkinter (3.3.2) some equivalent functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tkinter has a Scrollbar class that can be used to wrap widgets in a scrollbar. It may not be as concise to configure as perl, but you can set it up to do what you are asking for without too much hassle.

[Here](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-scrollbar-patterns.htm) are some examples of the scrollbar in use:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

listbox = Listbox(root)
listbox.pack()

for i in range(100):
   listbox.insert(END, i)

# attach listbox to scrollbar
listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

mainloop()
```

Comment: What a pity; the Perl/Tk way has less opportunities for errors :-).  Thanks!